# Properly add new columns to sales order grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento, grid, magento2

I created a module to add 2 columns in sales grid, shipping_information and tracking number.
The columns appears but when I tried to filter by Order ID in admin order page, example with 973, I  got this error

```
main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document\Interceptor) with the same ID "6245" already exists. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Item (Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponent\\DataProvider\\Document\\Interceptor) with the same ID \"6245\" already exists. at /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:404)"}
```

Also this error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous
```

But when I tried with another ID, the error disappear

In Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php

```
namespace Wetag\AdditionalOrderFields\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_order_grid',
        $resourceModel = \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order::class
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
    $joinTable_track = $this->getTable('sales_shipment_track');
    
    
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id', ['shipping_information'])->distinct();
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable_track, 'sales_order.entity_id = sales_shipment_track.order_id', ['track_number'])->distinct();
    parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
protected function _initSelect()  {

    $this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');
    $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
    parent::_initSelect();
  
   return $this; 

}
}
```

In Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
      </type>
</config>
```

In etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_sales" />
       </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

In Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
    
        <column name="shipping_information">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping method</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="track_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tracking number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I like to use the field shipping_information in order_sales_grid table, I didn’t get it without making a left join, I like to select this field without join

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by grouping by entity_id  **->group('main_table.entity_id')** to remove duplicaded rows and delete LeftJoin to Sales_order table since shipping_information already exists in sales_order_grid table

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $joinTable_track = $this->getTable('sales_shipment_track');
    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable_track, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_shipment_track.order_id', ['track_number'])->group('main_table.entity_id');
parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```